# Can Snape fly without metamorphosis?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Deathly Hallows:

> "No, he's not dead," said McGonagall bitterly. "Unlike Dumbledore, he was still carrying a wand...and he seems to have learned a few tricks from his master." With a tinge of horror, Harry saw in the distance a huge, batlike shape flying through the darkness toward the perimeter wall. (DH pg 599/482)

In the Goblet of Fire:

> “Maybe he didn’t want you to get there!” said Ron quickly. “Maybe - hang on - how fast d’you reckon he could’ve gotten down to the forest? D’you reckon he could’ve beaten you and Dumbledore there?”
>   “Not unless he can turn himself into a bat or something,” said Harry. “Wouldn’t put it past him,” Ron muttered.

So I always assumed Snape transformed into a bat when he jumped.

Then I saw on this site and wikia that many people think he could fly like Voldemort.

My question is: is there canonical proof that Snape could fly without metamorphosis?

Comment: "he seems to have learned a few tricks from his master" implies that he flew in the same manner as Voldemort, in human form. I always thought the resemblance to a bat was simply his cape fluttering in the wind.

Comment: Huh. Honestly, it never would have occurred to me to take one of Ron's offhanded, disgruntled comments as actual canon.

Comment: @Kevin Interesting. I had never thought of that before. But how would McGonagall know? She wasn't even involved in the 7 Potters, and he doesn't seem to have had any interaction with her before the Hogwarts siege.

Comment: @asymptotically She was in the Order, so she doubtless heard of that night's happenings from others in the Order.

Comment: not canon, but the movie clearly depicts him flying just like Voldemorte, as a sort of amorphous blob of smoke, and not shapeshifting into anything else.

Comment: In the film everyone can fly.

Comment: Yes, they call that disapparating, what a fail. @ALS

Comment: And my previous comment is for you too, @MichaelEdenfield

Comment: There used to be many fan theories about Snape being a Vampire.  This is partly based on how he's described to look like.  There's another throwaway joke too in Prisoner of Azkaban chapter 22 where Dean Thomas speculates they'd get a Vampire as the Defense Against the Dark Arts teacher next year.

Comment: It's a shame Snape didn't teach this new trick to Dumbledore before a certain event.

Comment: Kevin should make his comment into an answer so we can all upvote it.

Comment: This appears to be a completely separate question from the one it is closed as a duplicate of, nor is the answer the same. That question asks about something only in the movie(s) and how it can be justified in light of the books. This question is asking which of two methods of flying are used in the book.

Comment: @Solemnity too soon

Answer (score 6):

There is no evidence that he's actually an animagus. In fact, considering Snape's personality I would expect him to find a way to fly by himself without having to turn into a simple animal, like a normal wizard would. 
Just like Voldemort did, he found a way.... remember that Snape is (or tried to be) the Half Blood Prince, which, to me, was like a failed attempt of raising as a dark wizard (something that Voldemort actually succeeded on).

Comment: Note though that for the underwater task of the Triwizard Tournament, Viktor Krum has Transfigured himself to half a shark (*Goblet* chapter 27, “a human body in swimming trunks with the head of a shark”); and the impostor Moody has Transfigured Draco to a ferret.  Neither of those were Animagus transformations.