# What would happen if I were to cast "Loco-motor me"?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

The Locomotor spell is used whenever a wizard needs to carry a large load at about a walking pace. But what would happen if the wizard were to cast "Locomotor me" or "Locomotor [casters name]"?

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/why-can-objects-fly-and-people-other-than-dark-wizards-cant

Comment: Are you asking if the locomotor spell or wingardium leviosa spell could be used to make yourself fly?

Comment: Not sure, but it's possible their little baby sister could do it with them, and it would be easier than learning their ABCs....

Comment: It might throw an uncaught exception.

Comment: @EdmundDantes probably `'this' has no attribute locomote`

Comment: *Bootstrapping!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't know, but if anything, something might happen to their legs...

The Locomotor spell is only used a few times and always to move something large (as you mention);

- Tonk's uses the spell to move Harry's trunk. (*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter 3)
- Flitwick used the spell to move Trelawney's things back to her room. (*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter 26)

However, "Locomotor" is also used in two other spells, both which effect the legs of a person;

- Locomotor Mortis, the Leg-Locker Curse (*Philosopher's Stone*, Chapter 13)
- Locomotor Wibbly, the Jelly-Legs Curse (*Philospher's Stone*, Chapter 13)
- The final time we hear "Locomotor" is when McGonagall uses Piertotum Locomotor to animate the suits of armor (*Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 30)

So, at least half the time the "Locomotor" spell is used it is against another wizard, it uses a second spell word in conjunction, and affects the legs.

Comment: Essentially meaning locomotor = walk in one way or another.