# Could Severus Snape fly?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

In the question [Why did it seem like only Voldemort and Snape could fly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/why-did-it-seem-like-only-voldemort-and-snape-could-fly), it is said that Snape could fly. However, I don't remember reading it anywhere in the book.

Was it explicitly mentioned in the books (if so, where?) or is it not in the canon?

Comment: Only if he's a Balrog...

Comment: FYI: It's canon, not canons :) "An overall singular body of work"

Comment: @JimmyShelter OMG, does Snape have wings?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes it was, in Book 7.

> ... classroom where Professors McGonagall, Flitwick, and Sprout were standing at a smashed window.
>
> "He jumped," said Professor McGonagall as Harry and Luna ran into the room.
>
> "You mean he's dead?" Harry sprinted to the window, ignoring Flitwick's and Sprout's yells of shock at his sudden appearance.
>
> **"No, he's not dead," said McGonagall bitterly. "Unlike Dumbledore, he was still carrying a wand... and he seems to have learned a few tricks from his master."**
>
> **With a tingle of horror, Harry saw in the distance a huge, bat like shape flying through the darkness toward the perimeter wall.**
>
> *(Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter Thirty - The Sacking of Severus Snape)*

Comment: Some says because Snape is a vampire he can turn into a bat. But that is just mere gossip. lol